# Object clips into floor in material preview, but floats above it in render

Tags: rendering, materials, displacement

it's me

I'm back with another problem that is probably super easily solvable but with which I'm still struggling.

My object (in this case a person's robe) clips through the floor in material preview, which I did on purpose to try and compensate for what happens when I render it: namely, that the robe appears to levitate an inch above the floor. It didn't work, obviously, because even when I do that it's still offset in the render. I have the robe parented to the person it's on. At first I thought it was a midlevel thing on the displacement; they're all at their default .5 though and editing them makes it worse. So I'm stumped... Here's an example of what the robe looks like in both material preview and the render
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are there any hidden objects? Are you using any modifiers? Perhaps the floor has a displacement modifier, which is turned off in viewport display?

Comment: @Leander I have a subdivision and solidify modifier on the robe, and a collision modifier/sim on the floor...I tried applying the solidify modifier on the robe because it occurred to me that that might be the problem, but it didn't change anything...